# How to set a breakpoint on UIView hidden property?

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

I want to set a breakpoint on UIView hidden property, setHidden indeed, how do I do?
And I know execute in console(lldb): `b "-[UIViewController viewWillDisappear:]"` 
can set a symbolic breakpoint.

Comment: What language are you programming in? And why do you say `viewWillDisappear` when that has nothing to do with `setHidden:`? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You can set a symbolic breakpoint on "-[UIView setHidden:]" and if you want to break only on setHidden called on a specific instance then you can use "$arg1 == 0x7f9cbba75e60" as condition where $arg1 means self and 0x7f9cbba75e60 is the pointer of the view. Note that $arg1 does not work on 32bit simulator so you have to use 64bit simulator like iphone 5s simulator.

[image: symbolic breakpoint]